# Get count of occurrence max number

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to get the count of occurrence max number with just 1 input.

My code look like :-

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int max = 0, count = 0, value, lastValue = 0;

    while (num > 0){

        value = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        if (value > lastValue){
            max = value;
        }

        lastValue = value;
    }

    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println("count is " + count);
}
```

How i can calculate count of max numbers?

Assume i have input like `2556621` `count` should be `2`.

Comment: At what point are you stuck?

Comment: @pedromss getting count of max number since i'm using 1 input, it's easy with multiple input, but in my case how i can achieve that. ?

Comment: Why are you using one input then?

Comment: If only have one input, then you only have one number.  Are you familiar with the difference between a number and a digit?

Comment: Because count is never really used, count is zero..

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie i'm already getting each number in variable `value` so i think i can compare that.

Comment: @RC. i don't know how to use it then .

Comment: @android so you do not know the difference between a number and a digit.

Comment: This appears to be  homework

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie what the the similarities or advantage of your question and my question ???

Comment: Your question is just not valid, especially given the example. 2556621 is a number, hence the largest number in the input is 2556621, and it appears once. On the other hand, this input contains 7 digits, with the largest one being 6, and it appearing twice.

Comment: @YuvalBen-Arie  then it's not my problem that you don't under stand the code, and my comment above.

Comment: Of course, it is not your problem. You are just mistaken and stand corrected. Take it however you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like you code should be

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int max = 0, count = 0, value = 0;

    while (num > 0){

        value = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        if (value > max){
            max = value;
            count = 1;
        } else if (value == max){
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max); // 6 for 2556621 
    System.out.println("count is " + count); // 2 for 2556621
}
```